# How to have it so footer remains at bottom of page after scrolling into view?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a footer which is hidden below the fold of the viewport, because there is lots of content. I would like for it to show when I reach the end of the content, but stay fixed at the bottom of the screen. I would like for the content to be scrollable all the way to the bottom of the content to the top of the screen (minus the footer), like this (like how VSCode file scrolling works):

[image]

How can I make it so it works like that GIF above, yet the footer shows and sticks to the bottom of the screen while the content scrolls all the way to the top? The footer shouldn't show until it is possible to see, below all the content.

```css
#content {
  padding-bottom: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>LAST CONTENT</p>
</div>
<footer>I'm the footer</footer>
</div>
```

That snippet shows the footer after scrolling the content all the way to the top. I don't want that, I want the footer to show right after the bottom of the page, but to stay stuck at the bottom as you "finish" scrolling the content upward. Not sure how complex this needs to be and/or if it can be done in pure CSS/HTML (no JS). I don't mind either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after a sticky footer? But one which only shows up after you have scrolled all the way down? Perhaps an [intersection observer](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-01/intersection-observer/) would help?

```js
const observer1 = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting)
      footer.classList.add('visible')
    else
      footer.classList.remove('visible')
  })
})

observer1.observe(document.getElementById('spacer'))
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#spacer {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #bbb;
  background: #eee;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  position: sticky;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

footer.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>I’m the last paragraph of content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="spacer">I’m the spacer. The intersection observer watches me move in and out of the viewport and displays or hides the footer accordingly.</div>
  <footer>
    I’m the footer.
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting... If you scroll back down the footer stays, can that be fixed?

Comment: I have updated the snippet so that the footer shows when you scroll down to the bottom, then hides again when you scroll back up.